# How do I correct for daylight savings time with strtotime

Tags: php

I have a function that returns the new expiration for expired subscription renewals.  If the user renews for a month, the function looks like:

```
$unixtime = strtotime(" today + 1 month") + 86399;
$dt = date("Y-m-d", $unixtime) . ' at ' . date("H:i:s", $unixtime);
return array('unixtime' => $unixtime, 'dt' => $dt);
```

Today being February 10, I expected it to return dt as 2019-03-10 at 23:59:59.   However, it returned dt as 2019-03-11 at 00:59:59.  The unix epoch time returned is actually correct based on UTC, however when I return dt it does not take into account the change from standard time to DST.  I also suspect that when the times overlap in the fall the new expiration time will be an hour short, at 22:59:59.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you set up `date_default_timezone_set()` or equivalent?

Comment: Yes... date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Datetime` class](http://php.net/class.datetime) can handle that. Try the following code:

```
<?php

$today = new Datetime('today - 1 second');
var_dump($today->format(DATETIME::ATOM));

$expirationDate = $today->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
var_dump($expirationDate->format(DATETIME::ATOM));
```

Click [here](https://3v4l.org/lFZs4) for code on 3v4l.org.

Answer (score 0):

arueckauer answered my question... but while he was posting I was 2 finger hacking and came up with the following, which also works:

```
$dt = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", time());
$unixtime = strtotime("$dt + 1 month");
$newDT =  = date("Y-m-d", $unixtime) . ' at ' . date("H:i:s", $unixtime);
```

with unixtime being what the system looks at when a user logs in and newDT being what is displayed.